# decimal point issue once again

Tags: sql

The first line of code displays to 2 decimal points
The second line displays to 3 decimal points

```
SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[can]/1.2)) + SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[carton]/1.2)) AS [N],
(SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[can]/1.2)) + SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[carton]/1.2)))*0.2 AS [V]
```

Can someone please tell me how to get the second line to show 2 decimal points

Comment: And where exactly does C# fit in this?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using, which is presumably some version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the display, the do the cast to decimal *after* the calculation:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 2), SUM([can]/1.2)) + SUM([carton]/1.2)) AS [N],
```

You can do the conversion before, if you have a need to represent the some intermediate value as a decimal.  Do note, though, that SQL Server has quite arcane rules for the precision and scale of intermediate and final results when doing decimal arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the result to a 2 decimal place decimal:

```
select --just added to make the example runnable

SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[can]/1.2)) + SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[carton]/1.2)) AS [N],

CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), --add this line

    (SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[can]/1.2)) + SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[carton]/1.2)))*0.2

) --and an additional close bracket 
AS [V]

from (select 1.0 [can], 1.0 [carton] union all select 2.0, 3.0) x --just added to make the example runnable
```

The reason you're seeing 3 decimal places is because that's what the result of the calculation is; and when working with decimals SQL will output a decimal of the appropriate precision and scale to hold that result, unless you cast/convert it to something specific.

Comment: Thank you John. Shall remember this one in future

Comment: Hi @callasda if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You convert to 2 decimals using `CONVERT`...

```
SELECT
  SUM(CONVERT(decimal(8, 2), [can] / 1.2)) + SUM(CONVERT(decimal(8, 2), [carton] / 1.2)) AS [N],
  CONVERT(decimal(8, 2), ((SUM(CONVERT(decimal(8, 2), [can] / 1.2)) + SUM(CONVERT(decimal(8, 2), [carton] / 1.2))) * 0.2)) AS [V]
```